# how to compute an Array in VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6

I have a CSV file that will parse and put it to array. **Note** this is a big file.My questions are this how can i compute an Array in Vb6? Is it possible to have a computation in Array?

Comment: How big is big? what do you mean by 'compute an array'? do you mean you want to read in the file and put each line in a separate element of the array?

Comment: 1400 data in Array that's big it is. I'm asking if it is possible to get the difference of Array to Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to read in a file and it in an array you can do as follows:

```
'1 form with
'    1 command button: name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngLine As Long
  Dim intFile As Integer
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strData As String
  Dim strLine() As String
  'select file
  strFile = "c:\temp\file.txt"
  'read file
  intFile = FreeFile
  Open strFile For Input As #intFile
    strData = Input(LOF(intFile), #intFile)
  Close #intFile
  'put into array
  strLine = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
  'loop through complete array and print each element
  For lngLine = 0 To UBound(strLine)
    Print strLine(lngLine)
  Next lngLine
End Sub
```

this will read in the file, put it into an array (each line with its own element), and then loop through the whole array to print each line/element on the form

**[EDIT]**

below is an example how to substract items from an array from corresponding items from another array:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim lngIndex As Long
  Dim lngA(7) As Long
  Dim lngB(7) As Long
  'fill the arrays
  For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(lngA)
    lngA(lngIndex) = lngIndex + 1
  Next lngIndex
  For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(lngA)
    lngB(lngIndex) = (lngIndex + 1) ^ 2
  Next lngIndex
  'substract array a from array b
  For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(lngB)
    lngB(lngIndex) = lngB(lngIndex) - lngA(lngIndex)
  Next lngIndex
  'print arrays
  For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(lngA)
    Print CStr(lngA(lngIndex)) & " | " & CStr(lngB(lngIndex))
  Next lngIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a computation in array like this Array() - Array()?

Comment: I have a next question maybe you can also help me in this. I write the total of my array in a CSV file I used `writeline` to write it in CSV file. My problem is this everytime I write it in CSV file it will write but in the first column only, my question is this how can I write in the next column using writeline?

Comment: in a csv file columns are separated by comma's ... so to write the word "one" in column #1 and the word "two" in column #2 you have to write the following text to the file: "one" & "," & "two"

Comment: i have tried to pass my array to another array following your code but it cause me error `Subscript out of range` this is my code `If holder1 = "" Then
   For indx= 0 To UBound(t1)
      h1 = t1(indx)
   Next

   Else
      For indx= 0 To UBound(t1)
           t2(indx) = t1(indx)
      Next
 End If
 'subtract array t1 from t2
            If h1 <> "" And h2 <> "" Then
                For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(t1)
                    t3(indx) = t2(indx) - t1(indx)
                Next
            End If`

Comment: subscript out of range means you are trying to address an item in an array with an index that is either too high or too low ... to say anything about this error i need to see the declarations of your array variables .. if you post some code, always include the declarations of your variables

Comment: there are some comments i can make on the code you posted in the comment above: what are you trying to do with h1 in the first loop? after the loop ends it will always be equal to the last item of t1() ... why do you make t2 equal to t1 in the second loop ? in the third loop you substract t1 fromt2, but if they are equal, then you will always get 0 as the answer, so t3 will be an array in which each item is 0 ... how are t1 and t2 and t3 declared, what are the sizes of thes arrays ?